# Java + Kerberos - disable reverse DNS lookup

Tags: java, kerberos

We are using the Apache HttpClient library in order to connect to a Kerberos-secured REST endpoint which is behind a load balancer that serves multiple applications, so there is a mismatch between the forward and reverse DNS lookup results.

While we can successfully establish an authenticated session using cURL by setting rdns=false in the krb5.conf file, the same does not seem possible in Java - it is simply ignoring this setting and always performs the reverse DNS lookup, which of course fails the handshake due to the mismatch.

I haven't found too much information regarding this issue, but I did find this open Jira item, which explains the behavior we're seeing.. but does not provide any workaround:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189361

The only viable workaround I've found so far is to use a custom nameservice provider to "hijack" the reverse DNS lookups and return the desired hostname.
There is also very scarce information on this, but I found this blogpost from almost 12 years ago that still seems to work (although it feels like a pretty dirty hack):
http://rkuzmik.blogspot.co.il/2006/08/local-managed-dns-java_11.html

However it feels like I may be missing something here as it seems unlikely that there is so little information about this problem..

Has anyone else faced an issue with disabling reverse DNS lookups when doing Kerberos, in Java? If so, how did you resolve this.

Comment: Great research on this,  +1.  If I come across anything, I'll check back here.  What kind of load balancer are you using by the way?

Comment: This would be a hack too, but...on the load balancer, configure its Hosts file with the entries of the Kerberos-secured REST endpoints.  This way Java would be forced to honor what is set in the Hosts file at the load balancer level rather than looking at DNS first, and this would also negate the need to use a custom nameservice provider to hijack the reverse DNS lookups in order to return the desired hostname.

Comment: It is an F5 load balancer that is in front of a Cloud Foundry environment, it has a single VIP that routes traffic to the internal applications based on the host header.

We don't have access to it of course, but even if we did as far as I understand there is no way to control reverse lookup via the hosts file, it only affects forward lookups.

Comment: Side note about Apache HttpClient: quoting _Hadoop and Kerberos, the madness beyond the Gate_ "Why not use Apache HTTP Components? ... As the documentation says... _**if lucky it'll work**_ ... Don't waste time or make things worse: go with the JDK libraries from the outset" https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/web_and_rest.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same error last week when I was using a VIP but the reverse dns gave back to me the FQDN of the physical server.
Unfortunately I'm not using directly HttpClient-4.5.1 library but a software which is using it behind the scenes; for that reason I was looking for a solution without touching the source code of that software.
I did really a huge amount of tentatives (jvm spi.dns, jvm gss native, dnsjava.jar, ...) unfortunately without any success.
At the end, the "dirty solution" has been for me to rebuild the HttpClient jar changing the class "org.apache.http.impl.auth.GGSSchemeBase" on its method "String resolveCanonicalHostname(final String host)".

For a possible "good solution", I saw that this class is receiving the parameter "boolean useCanonicalHostname" directly in its constructor so, if you can work directly with HttpClient library, there might be a way to set this parameter to false somewhere and propagate it down to this class where the kerberos service ticket is generated (if the parameter is false, the rdns check is not done and the Host string is used instead).

I hope that this hint can help you.

BR

Samuele

Comment: Samuele, your post gave me the idea to take a second look at how we are using HttpClient and apparently yes, it is possible to disable the lookup of the canonical hostname in the SPNegoSchemeFactory method.


I will post the code that works - without dirty workarounds - below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue and after doing the investigation found that none of existing *Java* *HTTP*/*Kerberos* clients gives you full control over generation of *SPN*s. So I've started working on a standalone library which allows generation and validation of `Authorization: Negotiate XXX` / `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate XXX` *HTTP* headers.

It's called [Kerb4J](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j).

Consider you have a domain *cname.provider.acme.com* which is a CNAME (AKA alias) for domain *a.provider.acme.com* whose canonical *DNS* name (i.e. which is resolved after reverse DNS lookup) is *ptr.provider.acme.com*

You want to make a request to *cname.provider.acme.com* using your favorite *HTTP* client but do not want it to make any additional manipulations to *DNS* during *SPN* calculation.

```
URL url = new URL("http://cname.provider.acme.com/api/operation1");
SpnegoContext context = spnegoClient.createContext("http://cname.provider.acme.com"); // Will result in HTTP/cname.provider.acme.com SPN
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", context.createTokenAsAuthroizationHeader());
```

With *Kerb4J* you can even make *SPNEGO*-protected requests using an arbitrary *SPN* (useful say when testing code on local machine):

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/operation1");
SpnegoContext context = spnegoClient.createContext("http://cname.provider.acme.com"); // Will result in HTTP/cname.provider.acme.com SPN
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", context.createTokenAsAuthroizationHeader());
```

There's a released version available in [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kerb4j/kerb4j-client).

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of Kerb4J.*

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs into the same issue using the Apache HttpClient library, the following code works - the important bit is the constructor of SPNegoSchemeFactory which is:

```
public SPNegoSchemeFactory(final boolean stripPort, final boolean useCanonicalHostname)
```

Below is the Scala code that I am using right now:

```
  private val registry = RegistryBuilder
    .create()
    .register(AuthSchemes.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory(true,false))
    .build()
    .asInstanceOf[Lookup[AuthSchemeProvider]]

  private val credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider

  private val useJaasCreds = new Credentials()
  {
    def getPassword: String = null

    def getUserPrincipal: Principal = null
  }

  credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1, null), useJaasCreds)

  private val httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
    .create()
    .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(registry)
      .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
    .build()
```